# .NET web crawler needs to measure Time To First Byte of HttpWebResponse

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, httpresponse, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I have written a web crawler application that monitors a website, checking for issues. Each time it visits a page I want to capture the Time To First Byte (i.e. the time between making the request and the first byte of the response being received). TTFB is as close as you can get to measuring how long the server is taking to render a page.

Below is my code to do this, but the results don't look right. The TTFB is usually exactly the same as the full response time or a tiny fraction less. What am I missing?

```
HttpWebResponse webResponse = null;

var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
try
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
    webRequest.Method = "get";

    webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    webRequest.UserAgent = userAgent;
    webRequest.Accept = "*/*";
    webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    webRequest.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;

    webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

    responseTimeToFirstByte = Convert.ToInt32(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        bodyContent = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
        stopWatch.Stop();
    }

    webResponse.Close();
    responseTimeFull = Convert.ToInt32(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not missing anything. It is just that the framework is notifying the response when it is already buffered and parsed, when it is already there.

The `HttpWebResponse` object has already the information about the HTTP headers set, so the data has been already readed and parsed. Maybe sending a huge file you may find difference, and I am not completely sure.

If you want to measure the TFB, you can use a `Socket`, or better a `TcpClient` and send a crafted HTTP request, and then measure the time till you get data back:

```
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
Int32 readed = -1;
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
List<Int64> readTimes = new List<Int64>();

watch.Start();
await client.ConnectAsync(<IP address>, <Port>);
using(var stream = client.GetStream())
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    sw.WriteLine("GET /the/path/to/your/resource HTTP/1.1");
    sw.WriteLine("Host: yourdomainname.com");
    sw.WriteLine("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    sw.WriteLine();
    await sw.FlushAsync();

    while(readed != 0)
    {
        readed = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
        readTimes.Add(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        ms.Write(buffer,0,readed);
    }

    watch.Stop();
}
```

(Warning, this code is not tested)

In this code, the first value in "readTimes" would be your TFB, and the last one the total time.

Cheers.

Comment: @vortola - in your example, why do you use ConnectAsync? What difference does it make when you are awaiting the result on the same line?

Comment: The difference is that the execution thread will be released to do stuff somewhere else until the connection process ends, then the thread will comeback to continue with the rest of the method. You can use simple `Connect` and `Flush`, probably it won't make a difference if you are not doing some parallel intensive stuff.